# Replace a string with the date value from the row above

Tags: r, excel, date

I have a dataset where I have about 200 `\N` and I'd like to replace `\N` with the date/day value in the row above. Such as for row 641, I want to change the date to 10-Nov-14 and day to Mon:

[image]

If this can be done in R, does the format of date matter? As currently, these dates are shown as factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy in Excel. Replace all `\N` with nothing, select the two relevant columns, HOME > Editing, Find & Select, Go To Special..., Blanks, then

<kbd>=</kbd>

<kbd>`↑`</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then copy range again and HOME > Clipboard - Paste, Paste Special..., Values, OK over the top.

Comment: Excellent use of standard features and CTRL+ENTER to apply a formula to the whole selection.

Comment: sorry I am still confused about what you mean by =^(Up), when I tried type that in excel says there is a problem with the formula

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If that's an Excel file that you are importing into R then you need to understand how R works with the backslash characters (which is what is showing in the screenshot) and  which is used to "escape" characters. See `?Quotes`. Once the data is in R it will probably all be factor columns.

If the dataframe is named 'dat' then this should work to really make true missing values:

```
is.na( dat) <- dat == "\\N"  # need to escape the escape character.
```

Then use na.locf from package zoo:

```
library(zoo) # lots of useful methods in zoo.
dat$date <- na.locf(dat$date)
dat$day_of_week <-  na.locf(dat$day_of_week)
```

These methods should work with any class of column, and these would *not* be R Date-classed variables until you made the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved easily in R with the following code:

```
ListNa <- grep("\\N", a$date)
ListPrewRow <- ListNa-1
data[ListNa,c("date", "day")] <- data [ListPrewRow,c("date", "day")]
```

Where:

- "data" is the data table
- "date" and "day" is the columns to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done rapidly in Excel with a quick use of `Find` and `FindNext`.  Assuming you want to replace all of the `\N` on the `ActiveSheet`, this code will terminate once it has replaced them all.  `Offset(-1)` gets the value one row up.

```
Sub ReplaceWithValueAbove()

    Dim rng_search As Range
    Set rng_search = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("\N")

    While Not rng_search Is Nothing
        'set to row above
        rng_search = rng_search.Offset(-1)

        'find the next one
        Set rng_search = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.FindNext()
    Wend

End Sub
```

**Before and After pictures**

[image: before] [image: after]